# Error code 2755 when attempting to install Python 2.7.5 or 3.3.2

Tags: python, failed-installation

I am trying to install Python on my Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit machine, but after going through all of the installation settings 'n' stuff it shows this for a while:
[image: Installing..?]

before showing this, then the 'Installer quit prematurely' message and exiting:
[image: Oh dear...]

I have tried rebooting, redownloading twice, trying 3.3.2 instead of 2.7.5 etc etc.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: make sure you aren't installing the 64 bit version :)

Comment: @TehTris Good thinking! I am definitely installing the 32bit MSI.

Comment: Is your machine updated? Open a command prompt and type `msiexec` and then reply back with the version number.

Comment: Created the folder manually. It works.

Answer (score 38):

Make sure C:\Windows\Installer exists (if windows is installed in C:).

If it doesn't, just create it and run the installer again.

Comment: This fixed my problem installing VirtualBox 4.3.12.

Comment: Fixed my problem on Windows 8.1. I basically, deleted a lot of files to make hard drive space and one of them must have been the Installer directory, since Windows is a special folder in terms of permissions, you have to make the directory yourself for Installer to use.

Comment: Also have same promlem. Folder exists, but not accesible - cant change rights or own it. So i deleted it and create again and all works fine.

Comment: that was freaking it, thanks a lot I forgot that I got rid of that folder some time ago and was giving a big headache....

Comment: Awesome. Tried a lot of stuff but this simple thing worked in the end.

Comment: this is the best answer even microsoft itself has not provided this fix!

Comment: Fixed it on AWS win10 machine.

Answer (score 9):

Double check the file-permissions of the installer.

- Right-Click, and open the "Properties" window.
- Go to the "Security" Tab.
- Make sure the user `System` has `Read & Execute` permissions.
- If it's missing, click the `Edit` button and add that user manually.

See also: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2009-May/009090.html

[image: security options]

Comment: Worked for me for a custom 64bit [FlashFolder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flashfolder/)

Answer (score 3):

Try to run as Administrator and try to install to All Users.

If it still don't work try to install from commandline

> msiexec /i python-2.7.5.msi

Comment: Your solutions didn't work either... It may just be a problem with my installation of Windows, this laptop has been _far_ too heavily used (and fiddled with) for its own good. It works on my desktop, though, so crisis averted.

Comment: @condorcraft110 Strange. Maybe something messed MSI runtime, well as last resort you could run Portable Python on your laptop.

Comment: Portable Python? I've never heard of it, but it looks interesting. I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Old one, but finally figured this out: the answer came from https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2009-May/009090.html, and fixed this for me. The problem is that the MSI service (msiexec) runs as the SYSTEM user and doesn't have permissions to read the installer. To fix it, you need to:

1. Right-click on the file and open the Properties dialog.
2. Go to the Security tab.
3. Under the **Group or user names** box, select Add.
4. Type in SYSTEM (all caps) and then hit OK.
5. Make sure that user has Read and Read & Execute permissions.

Once I did this, it worked.

Comment: This fixed it for me, thanks.  My download folder is also used by Cygwin and had permissions such that the SYSTEM user couldn't execute it.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced this issue before. Check in C:\Windows if there is an installer folder. You need to enable viewing of Protected System files in order to see this folder. If the folder is missing, you can create it and ensure its hidden. Try to install again.

Comment: I have the same problem, this didn't help. To anyone else reading this: As far as I can remember, Windows needs this folder for the "add/remove programs" feature. Don't go about and delete files willy-nilly in there ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the installer itself is not encrypted. Go to the installer, right click, properties, advanced and uncheck the encrypt option. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try all the suggested answers which involves PERMISSION stuff, For me,
1. `C:\Windows\installer` folder exists already
2. Provide pemission for SYSTEM group read and execute(Right click msi and go for `security tab` and `edit` and add SYSTEM and provide read and execute permission)
3. Need to `run as Administator`. (right click msi if it doesn't show `run as admin` option then open cmd as `run as admin` and open msi file in that command prmpt.)

Its all related to extracting msi file content and putting it into right directory in windows folder so it requires PERMISSION.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install node.js MSI on Windows 10 and kept getting this error 2755. The following worked for me: search for **cmd** in the Start Menu, right-click it and **Run as Administrator**, and then run the following command:

```
msiexec /i filename.msi
```

This worked for me even when right-clicking the MSI file itself and running as admin did not. I also tried all the other listed solutions here (and rebooted) but only this allowed me to work around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the check mark from "encrypt contents to secure data" for the setup file in Properties->Advanced

Comment: I have already checked, the 'Encrypt contents to secure data' box isn't filled. Where does the Python installer unpack its files? - I have to go now, I'll be back tomorrow.

Comment: Maybe try installing other software than python distributions. It can be a major problem with your computer, not with the python installers

Comment: I tried running a few other MSIs I found lying around in my Downloads folder, and they all got to 'Validating install' before I stopped them (they were already installed). I am clueless as to what to do now, it seems only Python's installers refuse to install.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating new %windir%\installer and make it hidden. All of the sudden my Windows 8.1 couldn't install nothing at all. I've made some free space deleting "some unimportant" files :D

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same error from MSI files because they're downloaded from another computer.  In the general tab of the file properties simply click "Unblock".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was that I was running the MSI from a subst'd(*) drive.  Opening the same folder and the same MSI from its real path allowed the installation to continue.

Procmon log for the failure:

```
msiexec.exe CreateFile          D:\real\path   IS DIRECTORY
msiexec.exe FileSystemControl   D:\real\path   NOT REPARSE POINT
```

*) Specifically using this method:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices]
"X:"="\\??\\D:\\real\\path"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while installing NodeJs MSI. Follow the below steps to resolve the issue.
1.Right click on the MSI/Installer
2.Click on Properties
3.Click on Security Tab
5.if you did not find "SYSYETM" under Group or user names, Add "SYSTEM" with full permission  at least "Read and Execute" permission
6.  Then RUn as Administrator.

Then it will work

Answer (score -1):

[image]

If you are on windows, go to settings then security and deactivate folder protection